# Issues: Motion Planning & Trajectory Waypoints

Tags: ros, moveit, motionplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following [MoveIt Quickstart in RViz](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/quickstart_in_rviz/quickstart_in_rviz_tutorial.html#introspecting-trajectory-waypoints) tutorial. I chose the Specific Start/Goal States then I pressed "Plan" from the Motion planning panel but it didn't change anything or show the trajectory path.

Also in Motion Planning Slider, the waypoint is still numbered 0.
I set the start/goal of the robot arm to a different location without any collision.

Does anyone know why I cant witness any changes when I press Plan?

I'm curious about the error I got when I ran "roslaunch panda_moveit_config demo.launch rviz_tutorial:=true". It still opened RVIZ and I was able to upload panda_arm(motion planning).

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [moveit_ros_move_group/move_group]: Cannot locate node of type [move_group] in package [moveit_ros_move_group]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable (chmod +x)

ROS version: Noetic |
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393863/issues:-motion-planning-&-trajectory-waypoints/) by [ramdas369rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/92646/ramdas369rd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most likely your MoveIt package didn’t build properly.

Start by checking if the package is there:

```
rospack find moveit_ros_move_group
```

If it’s present, then you may need to look at reinstalling, try using `apt` instead.

Reference: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/1632

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0